# Play Video on refresh page JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have issue, I want the video to start to play after refresh page
as I make my video as autoplay

```
<video style="max-height: 100% ;max-width: 100%;" id="remoteVideo" controls autoplay 
playsinline></video>'
```

as javascript below it works only when I click the button
I want to play the video without button after refresh the page

```
window.onload  = function() {
    var btnVideo = document.getElementById("btn");
    btnVideo.style.display = 'block';
    btnVideo.addEventListener("click", playonRef);
}

function playonRef() {
    var lenVideo = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
    for (var i =0 ; i<=lenVideo.length ; i++){
        lenVideo[i].play();
    }
}
```

Comment: "it works only when I click the button" - that is of course absolutely on purpose, because you are not supposed to be able to "trick" your way around the autoplay restrictions like this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not autoplay a video/audio on page refresh. this is a security restriction. in order to play media, user needs to do some action in the page first. like clicking something.

Comment: youtube does autoplay video on page refresh